Regexp/grep to find one of two identical values, depending on a heading?
I have this output on the command line:
% pmset -g custom
Battery Power:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         2
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1
 lessbright           1
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10
AC Power:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      0
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         5
 womp                 1
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10

As you can see there are two copies of most entries, the only difference being the "headings" (Battery Power vs AC Power). The order of both the entries and the headings is not guaranteed. I want a robust way to find the value for displaysleep. That is, I want to specify Battery Power or AC Power and then get the displaysleep value for that section. Is there a better way than to "not break at linefeed" "non-greedy match"? Something like a hierarchical notation (pseudo code) "get AC 'Power.displaysleep'" à la XML, Java objects etc?

Regex has no notion of "hierarchy".

It sounds like you are interested in non-grep solutions as well so I'm adding sed and awk as tags

I don't have access to pmset but after reviewing this pmset man page I'm wondering if something like pmset -g -b displaysleep would work (-b == battery; replace -b with -c for wall charger/AC power); while it is possible to programmatically extract the desired data, is it possible to obtain the info via a few command line flags/args?

@markp-fuso Unfortunately, you cannot combine -g and -b, and you cannot specify displaysleep as an option to -g

Please reduce the example to a minimal input that demonstrates your needs, e.g. maybe 10 lines or less, and add the expected output given that sample input. See [ask] and in particular notice the part about providing a [mcve].

@EdMorton This is the minimal input.

@d-b no, it's not. You don't need 50 lines of input to demonstrate the need to print based on the value of a couple of lines. Less than 10 lines of sample input would be adequate, e.g. Battery Power plus 3 or 4 lines including 1 that's displaysleep then AC Power plus another 3 or 4 lines also  including 1 that's displaysleep.

If you don't mind combining awk with column, then it's really straight forward without needing to store any amount of data in arrays
pmset -g custom | 

awk '/^((AC|Battery) Power[:]$|[ \t]+displaysleep[ \t])/ && 
     (ORS = ORS < FS ? FS : RS)' | 

column -t

Output:
Battery  Power:  displaysleep  2
AC       Power:  displaysleep  5

From here, filtering AC Power vs. Battery Power is trivial.

I don't see that column -t adds value here.

@tripleee : you're right. it's just superficial formatting. I mentioned it so not to give off the misleading impression awk's output is already nicely columnized on its own.

Using awk:
function get_displaysleep_from_power () {
    pmset -g custom | awk -v heading="$1" '
    BEGIN {heading_found=0}
    {
        if(!heading_found){
            heading_found=match($1,"^"heading)
        }
        if (heading_found){
            if ($1 == "displaysleep") {
                print $2;
                exit
            }
        }
    }
    ' - 
}

get_displaysleep_from_power "AC"
get_displaysleep_from_power "Battery"

outputs:
5
2


I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let command output be
Battery Power:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         2
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1
 lessbright           1
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10
AC Power:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      0
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         5
 womp                 1
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10

then
command | awk '/^[A-Z]/{head=$1;next}{arr[head][$1]=$2}END{print arr["AC"]["displaysleep"]}'

gives output
5

Explanation: for lines starting with uppercase letter I set head value to 1st field (Battery and AC for given data) and instruct GNU AWK to go next line that is not doing anything more. For all others lines I set value in 2D array under head-1st field key. In END I print value under desired key.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

If you are looking for a robust way to create a hierarchical data structure from what you see output from pmset there are several ways:

Use awk in paragraph mode to easily catch the header and the time of interest;
Use a regex to parse all the output and build a hash from that;
Use the Apple tools to parse the binary plist file.

Here is a simple awk to get the value of displaysleep for all sections:
x=$(pmset -g custom | sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]][^:]*:)/\n\n\1/') 
echo "$x" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"} {
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~"^ displaysleep ") 
          print $1, $i
}'  

Prints:
Battery Power:  displaysleep         2
AC Power:  displaysleep         10

The problem with parsing the output from pmset -g custom is that the spaces may be ambiguous. Examples:

Both keys and values can have spaces and one or more spaces are used to delimit between key and value.

The value for the key "hibernatefile" is potentially a file with a space in it.

The key "sleep" not only reports status but may report the reason the actual state is different than assigned. If I enter pmset -g | grep ' sleep ' the return is  sleep                0 (sleep prevented by bluetoothd, coreaudiod, powerd, sharingd)


With those provisos, you can parse the output of pmset with the knowledge that some values for certain keys cannot be reliably parsed without further knowledge of that specific key.
Here is a Ruby that will parse the output of pmset -g custom into a Ruby hash. That hash can then be queried as a two level hash (["Battery Power"]["powermode"]) or turned into a structure like JSON to query in another way:
pmset -g custom | ruby -r json -e '
    dat=$<.read.scan(/^(\S+\s+Power:[\s\S]+?(?=(?:^\S+\s+Power:$)|\z))/).
    map{|a| sa=a[0].split(/:\s*\R[ \t]+/,2); [sa[0], sa[1].split(/\R[  \t]+/)]}.
    map{|sa| 
        [sa[0], sa[1].flatten.map{|s| s.scan(/^([^\n]+?)\s+(\S+$)/)}.
        flatten(1).to_h] }.
    to_h

#output that hash
puts "pmset -g custom as hash:\n#{dat}\n\n"

puts "\"Battery Power\".\"powermode\": #{dat["Battery Power"]["powermode"]}\n\n"

puts "pmset -g custom as JSON:\n#{JSON.pretty_generate(dat)}"'

Prints:
pmset -g custom as hash:
{"Battery Power"=>{"Sleep On Power Button"=>"1", "powermode"=>"0", "standby"=>"1", "ttyskeepawake"=>"1", "hibernatemode"=>"3", "powernap"=>"1", "hibernatefile"=>"/var/vm/sleepimage", "displaysleep"=>"2", "womp"=>"0", "networkoversleep"=>"0", "sleep"=>"1", "lessbright"=>"1", "tcpkeepalive"=>"1", "disksleep"=>"0"}, "AC Power"=>{"Sleep On Power Button"=>"1", "powermode"=>"0", "standby"=>"1", "ttyskeepawake"=>"1", "hibernatemode"=>"3", "powernap"=>"1", "hibernatefile"=>"/var/vm/sleepimage", "displaysleep"=>"10", "womp"=>"1", "networkoversleep"=>"0", "sleep"=>"0", "tcpkeepalive"=>"1", "disksleep"=>"0"}}

"Battery Power"."powermode": 0

pmset -g custom as JSON:
{
  "Battery Power": {
    "Sleep On Power Button": "1",
    "powermode": "0",
    "standby": "1",
    "ttyskeepawake": "1",
    "hibernatemode": "3",
    "powernap": "1",
    "hibernatefile": "/var/vm/sleepimage",
    "displaysleep": "2",
    "womp": "0",
    "networkoversleep": "0",
    "sleep": "1",
    "lessbright": "1",
    "tcpkeepalive": "1",
    "disksleep": "0"
  },
  "AC Power": {
    "Sleep On Power Button": "1",
    "powermode": "0",
    "standby": "1",
    "ttyskeepawake": "1",
    "hibernatemode": "3",
    "powernap": "1",
    "hibernatefile": "/var/vm/sleepimage",
    "displaysleep": "10",
    "womp": "1",
    "networkoversleep": "0",
    "sleep": "0",
    "tcpkeepalive": "1",
    "disksleep": "0"
  }
}

Alternatively, you can do it the proper Apple Way which is to reference the actual plist file.
Here is a Ruby that parses the plist file into XML:
ruby -e '

# Depending on the version of OS X, the plist can be at 
# /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
info_plist=File.read("/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist")

puts IO.popen("plutil -convert xml1 -r -o - -- -", "r+") {|f|
  f.write(info_plist)
  f.close_write
  info_plist = f.read # xml plist
}'

Prints:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AC Power</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DarkWakeBackgroundTasks</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Disk Sleep Timer</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Display Sleep Timer</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>System Sleep Timer</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Wake On LAN</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>Battery Power</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DarkWakeBackgroundTasks</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Disk Sleep Timer</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Display Sleep Timer</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>ReduceBrightness</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>System Sleep Timer</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Wake On LAN</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>SystemPowerSettings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Update DarkWakeBG Setting</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

You can then query that XML file.

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):
 f(){ p=${1:-Battery};
      pmset -g custom | sed -En '/:$/h;G;s/ (displaysleep.*)\n('$p'.*)/\2 \1/p'; }

Create a shell function that sends the output of the pmset command through sed and outputs by default Battery Power or AC Power if supplied with the parameter AC.

I wouldn't normally answer a question that doesn't contain an attempt by the OP to solve their own problem but since there are multiple answers already:
Using any awk:
$ pmset -g custom | awk -v pwr='Battery' -v tag='displaysleep' 'index($0,pwr" ")==1{p=1} p && $1==tag{print $2; exit}'
2


Assuming the headings don't appear anywhere else and aren't repeated, your question amounts to:

skip over stuff until
either of the headings is matched
skip over more stuff until
displaysleep is matched

And doing that twice
